# Looping Array in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have problem with my code here, I want convert serialize data in wordpress like this

```
$data ='a:2:{i:0;a:8:{s:8:"order_id";s:2:"19";s:5:"print";s:18:"type-canvas-framed";s:4:"size";s:12:"08-x-10-inch";s:18:"frame_canvas_color";s:10:"blackframe";s:11:"orientation";s:8:"portrait";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";d:42.990000000000002;s:8:"shipping";d:13.800000000000001;}i:1;a:7:{s:8:"order_id";s:2:"19";s:5:"print";s:11:"type-poster";s:4:"size";s:12:"36-x-48-inch";s:11:"orientation";s:8:"portrait";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";d:42.990000000000002;s:8:"shipping";d:14.800000000000001;}}' ;
```

I do parse the data using unseriliaze using unserialize the result like this

```
$result=array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'order_id' => '19',
    'print' => 'type-canvas-framed',
    'size' => '08-x-10-inch',
    'frame_canvas_color' => 'blackframe',
    'orientation' => 'portrait',
    'qty' => '1',
    'price' => 42.99,
    'shipping' => 13.8,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'order_id' => '19',
    'print' => 'type-poster',
    'size' => '36-x-48-inch',
    'orientation' => 'portrait',
    'qty' => '1',
    'price' => 42.99,
    'shipping' => 14.8,
  ),
);
```

I want to looping the array, how to do that in wordpress.

Thanks

Comment: Did looking up "Looping Array" not work? You may want to research more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

just use foreach

```
foreach($result as $key => $value ) {
    echo $value['order_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need wordpress specific functions for that use:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value){
    // process array
}
```